# onblur, only work once in jquery and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc-4

i tried validating some form fields in a web application made on MVC4, some fields must be validated with a regular expression i am using the event onblur but just work one time if you come back and type something wrong this event does not work anymore

my code for the event is this:

```
$('#Comprobante_FormaPago')[0].onblur = validaFormaPago;
```

and this are my functions:

```
function validar(re, campo) {
var textBox = campo[0].value;
var temp = textBox.match(re);
if (temp === null) {
    campo[0].className = "errorValiacion";
    return false;
} else {
    campo[0].className = "requerido";
    return true;
}
}

function validaFormaPago() {
    var campo_FormaPago= $('#Comprobante_FormaPago');
    var re = "[^\s]+[a-zA-Z ]*[^\s]+";
    validar(re, campo_FormaPago)

}
```

this only work one time

Comment: what kind of validation do you want to use with regular expression?

Answer (score 3):

Try using `onChange` instead which is called each time you change the value.  Whereas `onBlur` only fires when you move away from an object.

Answer (score 0):

Just regarding the regular expression itself, when passing a string argument to `match` you need to escape the backslashes:

```
var re = "[^\\s]+[a-zA-Z ]*[^\\s]+";
```

Or just use a regular expression literal:

```
var re = /\S+[a-z ]*\S+/i;
```

`\S` means a non-space character, and it is therefore equivalent to `[^\s]`.